# Как сделать резиновое меню ?

Tags: html, css

Ребят, нужно сделать резиновое меню, я знаю способ когда ul дают table-row а элементам списка li задавать table-cell, но при сужении экрана расстояние между элементами списка изменяется, есть ли способ сделать резиновое меню с сохранением расстояния ? Кода своего нет, потому как толком не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не только table может обеспечить **резиновое меню**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
ul:after {
  content: "1";
  margin-left: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Мои работы</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Технологии</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Блог</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Подключите Bootstrap, и попробуйте добавить в контейнер